# Can't see my OnePlus 7s Pro internal storage

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android, mtp

tl;dr I can't access my phone's internal storage for some reason, the device is registered as unknown MTP device in device manager

Tried alot of workarounds such as installing the Multimedia feature pack of for windows (did not work), checked the registry for a specific entry for portable devices (none were there) installed ADB (windows couldn't care less). One thing I haven't been able to try is manually installing wpdmtp.inf as the file is missing (probably because I have windows 10 pro N installed). There was also another solution based around the Media Transfer Protocol Porting Kit from Microsoft, but their website gives a dead link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download?first=71 (CTRL + F "porting")

Can someone share their wpdmtp.inf? The file is located inside C:/Windows/INF/ Its a file required for installing MTP drivers for MTP devices. Mine is missing and I haven't been able to find it anywhere locally or on the internet.

Its rather infuriating that I can't access my phone's files like this.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth` first. Windows 10 ISO can be downloaded [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) but you have to change browser's user-agent to Linux

Comment: @gronostaj sfc /scannow gave "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations" and DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth gave "No component store corruption detected. The operation completed successfully". However, I still encounter the same issue